# Google Maps API v3 - custom multi-colored icons

Tags: icons, google-maps-api-3

It seems like I have to assign an hosted image URL to a MarkerImage object to create custom icons. Is there a way to allow the user to pick a color to fill in this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Google Charts API to generate markers](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons.html#pins). You can choose the colour.

Answer (score 1):

Look for styled markers in [a list of Google Maps libraries](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries). This looks like it could help.

I would also look into generating the images on the fly with canvas and then producing a data URL:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```